# Forecasting ARMA process in matlab. An error message

Tags: matlab, forecasting

I am a beginner user in Matlab and I encountered a problem while trying to forecast values one step ahead in the future. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have ARMA(1,0,1) process and I would like to forecast returns one step ahead.

```
Mdl=arima(1,0,1)
EstMdl=estimate(Mdl,returns);
```

I tried to use function

```
[Y,YMSE] = forecast(Mdl,1)
```

But the result is an error message:

```
  Error using arima/forecast (line 273)
    Additive constant must be specified
```

Maybe somebody could give me an idea what its wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look at this, I think your problem is the number of inputs for `forecast`. You need to specify previous values.

Type `doc forecast` in the command line in MatLab to get help and examples...

Comment: Thanks Domi, I already found a mistake. It was only that in forecast function I need to write EstMdl, not Mdl.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the way you are using the forecast command. The first is that instead of Mdl you have to EstMdl as the first argument, the second is that when you forecast certain future values of the ARMA model (here only a single value) you have to specify the past values of the time-series. So the correct command should be [Y,YMSE] = forecast(Mdl,1,'Y0', y), where 'Y0' specifies the matrix/vector name of the previous values and y is the matrix/vector where they are stored (the variable representing the time-series).